# Handler()postDelay is unreachable for this Kotlin code, how to fix it?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a function, where I just explicitly want to delay the return value

```
private fun loadData(): DataModel? {
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(
    when (fetchStyle) {
        FetchStyle.FETCH_SUCCESS -> return DataModel("Data Loaded")
        FetchStyle.FETCH_EMPTY -> return DataModel("")
        FetchStyle.FETCH_ERROR -> throw IllegalStateException("Error Fetching")
    }, 3000)
}
```

However there's a warning state that `postDelayed` is unreachable, hence the 3s delay is not triggered.

To make it reachable, I have to add the extra parenthesis around

```
private fun loadData(): DataModel? {
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
    when (fetchStyle) {
        FetchStyle.FETCH_SUCCESS -> DataModel("Data Loaded")
        FetchStyle.FETCH_EMPTY -> DataModel("")
        FetchStyle.FETCH_ERROR -> throw IllegalStateException("Error Fetching")
    }}, 3000)
}
```

But then, I can't return the DataModel value anymore. How could I fix this to have the delay of 3s, while I could still return the respective DataModel or throw the exception?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here. Are you trying to wait 3 seconds before returning the `DataModel` from the `loadData` method? Do you want to block the current thread while doing so? How do you plan to actually call this function?

Comment: Ya, trying to wait 3 second, then return the DataModel from the loadData. It's okay to block the running thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to block the current thread, you can use `Thread.sleep`:

```
private fun loadData(): DataModel? {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    return when (fetchStyle) {
        FetchStyle.FETCH_SUCCESS -> DataModel("Data Loaded")
        FetchStyle.FETCH_EMPTY -> DataModel("")
        FetchStyle.FETCH_ERROR -> throw IllegalStateException("Error Fetching")
    }
}
```

---

An example for using `Handler` and `Runnable` instead, with a separate callback function:

```
private fun loadData(): DataModel? {
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        val result = when (fetchStyle) {
            FetchStyle.FETCH_SUCCESS -> DataModel("Data Loaded")
            FetchStyle.FETCH_EMPTY -> DataModel("")
            FetchStyle.FETCH_ERROR -> throw IllegalStateException("Error Fetching")
        }
        loadDataCallback(result)
    }, 3000)
}

fun useLoadData() {
    loadData()
}

private fun loadDataCallback(dataModel: DataModel?) {
    // use result here
}
```

A more Kotlin-like approach, passing a function as the callback:

```
private fun loadData(callback: (DataModel?) -> Unit): DataModel? {
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        val result = when (fetchStyle) {
            FetchStyle.FETCH_SUCCESS -> DataModel("Data Loaded")
            FetchStyle.FETCH_EMPTY -> DataModel("")
            FetchStyle.FETCH_ERROR -> throw IllegalStateException("Error Fetching")
        }
        callback(result)
    }, 3000)
}

fun useLoadData() {
    loadData { dataModel ->
        // use result here
    }
}
```

Note that these examples don't block any threads, and the `Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())` part of your original example code (that I kept for these examples) will place the execution of the `when` statement as well as the callbacks after that back on the main thread.

Comment: That solve my problem, thanks! Just realize that Runnable is not possible to return something. Would be curious if there's a way to make it do so?

Comment: I've added some examples for using `Handler` and `Runnable`.